# Line height default value if font size is 100%

Tags: css

I must override the body style of my page:

```
body{
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

override:

```
body{
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:?????;
}
```

What is the defualt value of `line-height` property if I specified `font-size:100%` ?

Is there a strict relation between this properties ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[The default `line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height) is `normal`, so use:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

FYI, you can confirm this if you have Chrome by opening up a website, inspecting the `<body>` element and viewing the inherited computed styles.

Comment: But for the records, this `normal` value corresponds to what size? `1.38`?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger from mdn: Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family.

Answer (score 10):

Set a unitless value of `1`, which will multiply the calculated font-size (i.e. how big the font turns out to be) with 1, making for a high-enough line-height.

You can also use `1.5` for a little more spacing.

So to finish your code it would be

```
body{
  font-size:100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

See the part on  at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height for more details. Using a unitless number is stated as the preferred way of setting line-height.

Comment: For reference, setting it to `1` is also what the [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) does.

Answer (score 6):

> #### Values
>
> `normal`
>
> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly **`1.2`**, depending on the element's `font-family`.
>
> ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values

Answer (score 3):

The default line height is roughly ~1.1em (see [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/fonts)).

You can change the relationship between the line-height and the font-size however, using for example:

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.618;
}
```

To take a more in depth look at the relationship between line-height and font-size, a good place to start would be:
http://demosthenes.info/blog/606/Molten-Leading-Exploring-The-CSS-Relationship-Between-Font-Size-Line-Height-and-Margin

Comment: Actually default line-height is 1.3EM (130%) because with smalled line height characters that go under and above the line would collide in multi-line text. (Try first line of "jyg" and second line of "ŠÝŮ".)

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative `line-height`

If your original sizes have been `font-size:14px;` and `line-height:20px;` and you want to keep the same proportions you can use 1 * (20/14) em so `line-height:1.42em;`

```
body{
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:1.42em;
}
```

Comment: to quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height): `Percentage and em values may have unexpected results, see "Notes" section.`

Comment: @Christoph True, but the question is about what value will be correct to replace the pixel values if he is going to use percentages, so I think your comment would be good on the question itself to inform the readers. Good quote anyways.

Answer (score 0):

#### // default line-height will be 25px

```
body{
font-size:100%;
line-height:25px;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.