# Vertical dimensions of inline-block elements with text of different font size

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, font-size

I have a series of elements with display:inline-block. They contain text of different font-sizes, and are displayed next to each other.

I am trying to understand where the vertical dimensions of the elements come from.

Here is the simple code :

```
<a class="icon"></a>
<a>H</a>
<a class="icon"></a>
<a>H</a>
<a class="icon"></a>
```

and the CSS :

```
a {
  font-family: consolas;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.icon:before {
  content: "H";
  font-size: 44px;
}

a:not(:empty) {
  padding: 25px; // (44-14) / 2 + 10
}
```

Now, contrary to what I would expect, 25px is not the correct value for padding to compensate the font size difference, but 27px is.

**I don't really understand why the text height for font-size: 44px is actually 51px and for 14px it is 17px.**

Once these values are taken into account, it makes sense (51 - 17) / 2 + 10 = 27 is the right padding compensation.

[See fiddle here](http://codepen.io/istrasoft/pen/gldEn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with `line-height`

Set the `font-size` and the `line-height` to be the same if you want them to line up.

[***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kqcfr)

Comment: Indeed it does work with line-height, but the question here was to understand why, without setting line height explicitly, the values are different from the font-size values specified, and where they come from ?

Comment: Because the default `line-height` is around ~1.1 times the value of the `font-size` as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163788/line-height-default-value-if-font-size-is-100)

Answer (score 0):

For an inline element, which is what a `:before` pseudo-element is by default, the height is determined in a manner that depends on the font and on the browser, by the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced).

If you set `display: inline-block` on the `:before` pseudo-element, then you can set its height using the `height` property, if desired.